# How to send Emoji with Telegram Bot API?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I need to send messages containing emoji with my Telegram Bot.

So I copy/paste emoji code `:nine:` for example, in my message text and send it to a user, BUT emoji didn`t work.

This is my sample code and function:

```
function tel_send($key, $t, $c)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $key . "/sendMessage");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cache=" . (time() / rand(1, time() - 100)) . "&text=" . $t . "&chat_id=" . $c);
    $ss = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ss;
}
tel_send($key, "My number - :nine:", $val['message']['chat']['id']);
```

So, my question is: How can I send emoji by Telegram bot?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you need to specify emoji's unicode value.

[check here](https://github.com/mustafababil/Telegram-Weather-Bot/blob/master/responseController.py#L11)

these are returned by a function as emoji value like  u'\U000026C4' which is snowman. although it is in python, you can apply it for php.

Comment: In PHP, remember to use byte codes inside double quoted strings

Comment: Not all emoji in your link. E.g. there is no `index finger up` emogi, `:point_up:` shortcode.

Comment: you can find complete list of emoji [here](https://github.com/shanraisshan/EmojiCodeSheet)

Answer (score 64):

I faced the same issue a few days ago..
The solution is to use Bytes (UTF-8) notation from this table:
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

examples:

\xF0\x9F\x98\x81     GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES

\xF0\x9F\x98\x89     WINKING FACE

Comment: Sucesfully used this with a PHP bot.  +1 for providing so excellent link with that format emojis codes.

Comment: In PHP, remember to use it inside a double quoted string.

Comment: This is the only way to get emoji's working when calling the API url directly.

Comment: Awesome, should be the accepted answer. This is the updated link: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Answer (score 10):

See emojis and their UTF-8 codes here:
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Then you must convert UTF-8 codes to Telegram-ready response text with the following code:

```php
<?php

function telegram_emoji($utf8emoji) {
    preg_replace_callback(
        '@\\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})@x',
        function ($captures) {
            return chr(hexdec($captures[1]));
        },
        $utf8emoji
    );

    return $utf8emoji;
}

$utf8emoji = '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81';

$telegramReadyResponse = 'Hi user ' . telegram_emoji($utf8emoji);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just copy emojy from telegram and paste in text to send like

```
$bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/";
$url        = $bot_url . "sendPhoto?chat_id=@Your chanel user";

$post_fields = array(
    'chat_id'   => $chat_id,
    'caption'   => 'Test caption ',
    'photo'     => new CURLFile(realpath("logo.jpg"))
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

another way you can use the name of shap ,for example for home you can use `:house:`
example:

```
:phone:
:white_check_mark:
:factory:
:page_with_curl:
```

Comment: All ingenious is simple ) I spent a lot of time before I saw your answer )
This is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: All ingenious is simple ) I spent a lot of time before I saw your answer )
This is the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I am using this code at linux bash and curl command for grinning face

```
curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage" -d "chat_id=ID&text=%F0%9F%98%80&parse_modwarninge=Markdown"
```

Answer (score 4):

Real solution is to use https://github.com/spatie/emoji (`composer require spatie/emoji`) for Emoji codes. Now your code will look like

```
Emoji::CHARACTER_EYES
```

or

```
Emoji::eyes()
```

This is something you could really use. Unlike writing all the codes manually and having hard time understanding what is it on the first glance.

Answer (score 3):

## > PHP 7

You just to use the `\u` and the unicode literal like following:

```php
$emojie = "\u{1F600}";
```

Resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548423/8760592

Answer (score 3):

IMPORTANT THING:

No one said it.

You have to use double quote, not single ones.
Code below will give you just text: `\xF0\x9F\x98\x822021-11-21 09:54:25`

```
define('TELEGRAM_TOKEN', '9999999999:FFFFFFFFFFFFraxb6jajm8cDlKPOH-FFFFFFF');

define('TELEGRAM_CHATID', '@my_bot');  

message_to_telegram('\xF0\x9F\x98\x82' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

function message_to_telegram($text)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TELEGRAM_TOKEN . '/sendMessage',
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'chat_id' => TELEGRAM_CHATID,
                'text' => $text,
            ),
        )
    );
    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

But with double quotes you'll get emoji:

```
message_to_telegram("\xF0\x9F\x98\x82" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 1):

An addition to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431810/1114926.

The link that [Mustafa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1186532/mustafa) provided doesn't represent all emoji. This source is better http://emojipedia.org/ ☝️. It has variations of emoji in addition to the  major sign.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for an answer for this for a long time, but could not get it working. my scripting skills are poor and converting php answers to bash proved a challenge.

But, nonetheless I got it working with a most simple solution:
I went to telegram desktop messenger, there i send the required emoji ().

Than I made a variable: bus=""

Now I can use the variable in the curl as: "text=some text $bus"

This works great using bash on linux, I suppose it could also work in php.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to just copy and past the emoji you need in your code.
But then you will have to make sure your source code files are stored UTF8

I just opened Telegram on my system and copied the ones I needed and never looked back :) Funny thing is that I do not have to work with constants, specific names 
or the unicode character value. I can directly see what emoji is used IN MY EDITOR.

```
$message = 'Pointing down: ';
```

If you process that into a message (example above is PHP, but I guess it will work in any programming language)

Answer (score 1):

You need to json_decode unicode value first, try like this.

```
json_decode('"\ud83d\ude0a"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another choice 
$curl  .... -F text="&#x1F601" -F parse_mode=html .... "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage"

will enable parse_mode to html and use HTML hexadecimal (hex) reference(&#x1F601) for unicode U+1F601

Answer (score 0):

Note that, at least with JavaScript/Node.js, you can just paste the emoticon's directly into the code and they translate find into the Telegram API. EG.

Answer (score 0):

to get smileys and emojis.. you can always reference this emoji documentation for DEVs
https://carpedm20.github.io/emoji/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32269463)