# How to convert Emoji from Unicode in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, emoji

I use this [table of Emoji](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) and try this code:

```
<?php print json_decode('"\u2600"'); // This convert to ☀ (black sun with rays) ?>
```

If I try to convert this [\u1F600](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F600) (grinning face) through `json_decode`, I see this symbol — `ὠ0`.

Whats wrong? How to get right Emoji?

Comment: Did you try the bytes notation? [echo "\xF0\x9F\x98\x80";](https://eval.in/463740) Maybe your browser can't display this one?

Comment: If you save the PHP file in the correct encoding you can also just write `print('');`.

Comment: If you problem is related to how to save them in database if you are using MySQL you can change the chartset to `utfbm4`. Take a look to [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/16576).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**PHP 5**

JSON's `\u` can only handle one UTF-16 code unit at a time, so you need to write the surrogate pair instead. For [`U+1F600`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F600/index.htm) this is `\uD83D\uDE00`, which works:

```
echo json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE00"');
```

**PHP 7**

You now no longer need to use `json_decode` and can just use the `\u` and the unicode literal:

```
echo "\u{1F30F}";
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answer of Tino, I'd like to add code to convert hexadecimal code like `0x1F63C` to a unicode symbol in **PHP5** with splitting it to a surrogate pair:

```
function codeToSymbol($em) {
    if($em > 0x10000) {
        $first = (($em - 0x10000) >> 10) + 0xD800;
        $second = (($em - 0x10000) % 0x400) + 0xDC00;
        return json_decode('"' . sprintf("\\u%X\\u%X", $first, $second) . '"');
    } else {
        return json_decode('"' . sprintf("\\u%X", $em) . '"');
    }
}
```

`echo codeToSymbol(0x1F63C);` outputs

Answer (score 0):

Example of code parsing string including emoji unicode format

```
$str = 'Test emoji \U0001F607 \U0001F63C';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/\\\U([A-F0-9]+)/',
    function ($matches) {
        return mb_convert_encoding(hex2bin($matches[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32');
    },
    $str
);
```

Output: Test emoji

https://3v4l.org/63dUR

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).