# How to show emojis in PHP

Tags: php

I have setup a twiml app in twillio which forward/post all sms (which came to my twillio number) to a domain .
On that domain i can get message body.issue is when some one send emojis in SMS .
for this i did json_encode($sms->body); which show me emojis like this.
"\u263a\ud83d\ude00\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude03" (these are some emojis which came through SMS)

i did json_decode() as well for above text but it not shows me correct emojis icons. it shows like this (â˜ºðŸ˜€ðŸ˜ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜ƒ)

Which encoding or decoding i should use please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Emoji from Unicode in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547233/how-to-convert-emoji-from-unicode-in-php)

Comment: @MateiMihai sir i try the above as well but not helpful .
if we write 
echo json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE00"'); in php file it won't show smiley face
i try it in chrome/firefox but noting happens.

Comment: I think depends on the font used.. the font should support those emoji

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to follow these steps
1. make sure you have set
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
2. use this method

```
function decodeEmoticons($src) {
    $replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,4})/i", "&#x$1;", $src);
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-16", "HTML-ENTITIES");
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'utf-16');
    return $result;
}
$src = "\u263a\ud83d\ude00\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude03";
echo decodeEmoticons($src);
```

it will shows you the emojis icons

Answer (score 0):

See first of all check in your database Collation and set utf8_general_ci after that check your table Collation and set utf8_unicode_ci  OR utf8_general_ci