# PHP 7.1 decode emoji sent by JS

Tags: php, emoji

I've sent a query string like this by JS to a PHP 7.1 app

```
?com=item&title=Hello%uD83D%uDE99
```

and should get

```
Hello
```

but it is

```
Hello??????
```

Please F1...:)

I use JSHttpRequest class to do so

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, it is "Hello??????"? How do you observe this?

Comment: I used every thing, **json_decode($_GET['title']) ** , **print_r($_GET)** , **preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]+)/', function ($match) {
   return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}, $str); return $str;**     and so on...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show emojis in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410967/how-to-show-emojis-in-php)

Comment: @rtfm now it is **Helloí ½íº**

Comment: `Hello%uD83D%uDE99` turned in to `Salamí ½íºa` well thats odd, how about posting the code you used

Comment: @rtfm   function decodeEmoticons($src) {
    $replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,4})/i", "&#x$1;", $src);
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-16", "HTML-ENTITIES");
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'utf-16');
    return $result;
}

Comment: look at the input, one simple change will make this work

Comment: thanks @rtfm, i collect data with json and then serialize it and send via AJAX. so i have some restrictions. OK i'll try to change the input

Comment: % to \ will make the above function work

Answer (score 0):

Added this line:

```
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace(/\%(u[0-9a-f]{4})/ig, '\\$1');
```

before

```
xr.send(this.queryText);
this.span = null;
```

in JsHttpRequest.js:422 to fix query string

ThanX to all