# I was able to save emojis in my database but when I retrieve it, it shows unicodes

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I already set my database and tables into utf8mb4_bin and utf8mb4_unicode_ci

```
header('Content-type text/html; charset=UTF-8');
include 'DATABASE.php';
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

setting the character sets client, results, and connection into utf8mb4

```
$query =$connect->query("SET character_set_client=utf8mb4");
$query =$connect->query("SET character_set_results=utf8mb4");
$query =$connect->query("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4");

$query = "
      SELECT * FROM tbl_comment 
      WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' 
      ORDER BY comment_id DESC";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
```

Check sender name if he/she has commented

```
checkSenderNameinDB($username);
```

Displaying data

```
foreach($result as $row){
  if(strcmp($row["comment_sender_name"],$username)==0){ 
      $output .= '
          <div class="card light" style="border-left:none; border-right:none;"> <div class="card-content">
  <div class="card-header text-white bg-secondary" >By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> <i id="facebook_time_ago" title="'.$row["datesent"].'">'.facebook_time_ago($row["datesent"]).'</i></div>
  <div class="card-body text-dark">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
  <div class="card-footer text-dark" align="right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply text-dark" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" title="Reply"><i class="fas fa-reply text-primary"></i></button>'.

  ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-default text-danger delete" name="delete" data-id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" title="Remove/Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default text-dark edit" name="edit" data-id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" title="Edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></div>'.'</div>';}
```

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_ci sir

Comment: you mean the comments itself? its VARCHAR

Comment: Can i add you on FB in order for me to explain and show it to you in a clearer way aobut my problem :)

Comment: theres no NVARCHAR in mysql sir

Comment: @Gene Phillip Astista, can you check [How to show emojis in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410967/how-to-show-emojis-in-php) and [How to convert Emoji from Unicode in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547233/how-to-convert-emoji-from-unicode-in-php)

Comment: *"theres no NVARCHAR in mysql sir "* What does MySQL have to do with the question? You've tagged SQL Server. SQL Server has `nvarchar`, and if you're storing emoticons yiou **need** to use `nvarchar`.

Comment: CODE FOR LOADING THE COMMMENTS                                                                 `function load_comment(){ 
               $.ajax({
                  url:'fetch_comment.php',
                  method:'POST',
                  success:function(data){
                   $('#display_comment').html(data);
            }});}`

Comment: the above `code` is when i try to update/add/delete some comments, it will load all the comments for a real-time system, emojis are now showing but the second problem is when I load my comments the emojis turning into a unicode again :( then if i refresh only the webpage it turns back into emojis again