# how to convert Unicode into character

Tags: php, unicode, emoji

Hey I am trying to convert this unicode :

```
U+1F61D
```

into this character:

But I am unable to find a suitable way to do this in php, this site https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ is converting it very easily.

To solve this I follow the instruction explain in this question : [How to convert Emoji from Unicode in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547233/how-to-convert-emoji-from-unicode-in-php)

When I tried this code I am getting weird character. I am unable to understand how to generate surrogate.

I am using this code:

```
echo json_decode('"\u1F61D"');
```

This gives me this character:

```
ὡD
```

Here I want to generate surrogates for the above unicode so my question is different.

Comment: If you're trying to use json_decode, you'll need to grab the javascript variant from that file. `json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE1D"')` gives you the emoji you want.

Comment: the question is how can i do that can I do it in php